# Implementing SPI library in Arduino (how do classes work?)

Tags: class, memory, arduino, shared-libraries, spi

I am currently trying to self learn Arduino/C programming/Assembly. I am working on a project which requires a lot of data collection, and by research I discovered a chip called the "23K256" from Microchip (see here: http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en539039). Moreover,  I have also discovered that an Arduino library taking advantage of this chip exists (see here: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/SpiRAM). I downloaded the "spiRAM3a.zip" file, which I believe is the one most up-to-date. Note that I have only recently downloaded the Arduino software and thus have the latest version installed (I believe it's 1.0.6). Also note that I'm using Arduino Uno, although I will eventually need to use Arduino Mega (I just want this working on ANYTHING at this point). With this library is some code that exemplifies its use to read and write to the 23K256 (the file name is "SpiRAM_Example" included in the package I downloaded), effectively increasing the SRAM on Arduino available. Here is the actual, exact code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SpiRAM.h>

#define SS_PIN 10

byte clock = 0;
SpiRAM SpiRam(0, SS_PIN);

void setup()   {                
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()                    
{
  char data_to_chip[17] = "Testing 90123456";
  char data_from_chip[17] = "                ";
  int i = 0;

  // Write some data to RAM
  SpiRam.write_stream(0, data_to_chip, 16);
  delay(100);

  // Read it back to a different buffer
  SpiRam.read_stream(0, data_from_chip, 16);

  // Write it to the serial port
  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    Serial.print(data_from_chip[i]);
  }
  Serial.print("\n");
  delay(1000);                  // wait for a second
}
```

My problem is that when I complie the code, to test my confguration and try to learn its use, I surprisingly get an error. This is what I get:

SpiRAM_Example:7: error: 'SpiRAM' does not name a type

SpiRAM_Example.ino: In function 'void loop()':

SpiRAM_Example:20: 'SpiRAM' was not declared in this scope

So it's basically telling me that there's something wrong with the `SpiRAM SpiRam(0, SS_PIN);`line of code. My question is, why? Am I misunderstanding something very fundamental about how classes work? I feel like I must not be doing something because I highly doubt an incorrect piece of code would be published on Arduino's website. How can I get this code to compile, or at least be able to simply use this library? Should I post the code for the library itself ("SpiRAM.h"), which was included in the package I downloaded?

I would really appreciate any help I can get, and sincerely apologize if this is a really dumb question. I think this is the first I've worked with classes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download Attach:spiRAM3a.zip or the original? I installed this and your code. It complies on the IDE 1.05

Answer (score -5):

The error `'SpiRAM' does not name a type` typically occurs when the compiler encounters a symbol that it doesn't recognize or when it expects a type name but doesn't find one¹. In your case, it seems like the compiler is unable to recognize `SpiRAM` as a type.

This could be due to several reasons:

1. The `SpiRAM.h` file is not correctly included or not found in the library path. Make sure that the `SpiRAM.h` file is in the correct directory and the library is properly installed.
2. There might be an issue with the order of declaration. The C++ compiler needs to know about a type before you use it¹. If `SpiRAM` is defined after it's used, you might encounter this error¹.
3. There could be a naming conflict. If there's another symbol with the same name `SpiRAM`, it might cause this error.

Here are some steps you can take to resolve this issue:

- Check if the library is correctly installed and `SpiRAM.h` is in the correct path.
- Make sure there's no naming conflict with `SpiRAM`.
- Try cleaning and rebuilding your project.
- If none of these work, you might want to consider reaching out to the library author or the Arduino community for more specific help.

Remember, there's no such thing as a dumb question when learning something new. Keep exploring and happy coding!